# Accessing image from the other server

Tags: php

I am trying to make a php "image downloader", and so far everything is going just the way i want. The problem which I'm facing is probably some kind of security of the server i'm trying to access. So for example this [**url**](https://yande.re/sample/2f7b6c5d87d90f173769d999e60861c8/yande.re%20250521%20sample.jpg) would show you the image I want to download with my server.

But if I try to at least display that image with that url in my website it simply doesn't appear. I can't show the url of my website, but it's just a simple `<img />` tag nothing else.

Is there any way around this or should i just quit?

P.S just to make this clear that my code isn't wrong i can download any amounts of images from other websites I have tried so far. And don't ask me for the code since even `<img src="url_here.jpg" />` doesn't work, so it's pointless to look at php code.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that you have no control over this other server and are pulling images without permission? They probably have some anti-leech controls in place.

Comment: @j08691 Yes you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would not appear because the other server is preventing hot linking of images.

A typical example would be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yande.re/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|css)$ - [F]
```

The solution.

- Load the image via curl
- Save to a CDN
- Then display it on your site

**Prove of Cencept**

```
$url = 'https://yande.re/sample/2f7b6c5d87d90f173769d999e60861c8/yande.re%20250521%20sample.jpg';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://yande.re");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// $data is file data
$post   = array('image' => base64_encode($data), 'key' => "YOUR_API_KEY_ITS_FREE");
$timeout = 30;
$curl    = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

$json = json_decode($json);
printf("<img src\"%s\" / >",$json->upload->links->small_square);
```

Output

[image]

Comment: could you explain about cdn?

Comment: CDN IS [Content Delivery Netword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and so many of them available rather than server the image directly from your server

Comment: Well your suggestion helped, thou i had to install curl on my server, but it works now, thank you.